# 30 second offset with smalldatetime comparison on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, smalldatetime

I've came across an odd problem while comparing dates (actually smalldatetime) in SQL Server. It seems like there is a 30 seconds offset/bias while comparing dates close to the end of the day:

This is correct:

[image]

But this is definitely not correct:

[image]

What is happening here? Is math broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`smalldatetime` type has a accuracy of one minute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql) so the literal '2019-12-31 23:59:30' is rounded to '2020-01-01 00:00:00'.

Answer (score 4):

If you read the [documentation][1] for `smalldatetime`, you will see this note:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

> Accuracy  One minute

In other words, the literal value is being rounded.  As a result, what-you-see-is-not-what-you-get.

Comment: Right, try to enter data in the table with smalldatetime: one value with seconds, one without.  It won't let me add the value with seconds.